# HockeyApp crash report

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5, crash-reports, hockeyapp

I have an app with HockeyApp integrated for crash reporting.
yesterday i have recieved a crash report stated below.

```
Incident Identifier: B797B4D3-EA8D-4226-8B0E-11149ADC20B7

CrashReporter Key:   55E9EBD1-9990-44EF-98E8-C0A000955CED

Hardware Model:      iPhone5,2

Process:         AppName [1375]

Path:            /Users/USER/AppName.app/AppName

Identifier:      ----------------------------

Version:         1.0.0
Code Type:       ARM
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2013-10-21T18:04:47Z
OS Version:      iPhone OS 7.0.2 (11A501)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  SIGABRT
Exception Codes: #0 at 0x38f341fc
Crashed Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x2e689e8b <redacted> + 131
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x389846c7 _objc_exception_throw + 39
2   CoreFoundation                      0x2e5bfe65 <redacted> + 233
3   AppName                             0x000ac04d 0x66000 + 286797
4   AppName                             0x000abf17 0x66000 + 286487
5   Foundation                          0x2f06ee6d ___NSFireTimer + 65
6   CoreFoundation                      0x2e654e87 <redacted> + 15
7   CoreFoundation                      0x2e654aa3 <redacted> + 795
8   CoreFoundation                      0x2e652e2b <redacted> + 1219
9   CoreFoundation                      0x2e5bd541 _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 525
10  CoreFoundation                      0x2e5bd323 _CFRunLoopRunInMode + 107
11  GraphicsServices                    0x332f42eb _GSEventRunModal + 139
12  UIKit                               0x30e741e5 _UIApplicationMain + 1137
13  AppName                             0x000b6cd7 0x66000 + 330967
14  libdyld.dylib                       0x38e7dab7 <redacted> + 3


Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x38f341fc ___pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x38ee502d _abort + 77
2   AppName                             0x000e41ff 0x66000 + 516607
3   CoreFoundation                      0x2e68a18d <redacted> + 581
4   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x38984927 <redacted> + 175
5   libc++abi.dylib                     0x3834a1b3 <redacted> + 79
6   libc++abi.dylib                     0x38349d17 ___cxa_rethrow + 103
7   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x3898480f _objc_exception_rethrow + 43
8   CoreFoundation                      0x2e5bd5b7 _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 643
9   CoreFoundation                      0x2e5bd323 _CFRunLoopRunInMode + 107
10  GraphicsServices                    0x332f42eb _GSEventRunModal + 139
11  UIKit                               0x30e741e5 _UIApplicationMain + 1137
12  AppName                             0x000b6cd7 0x66000 + 330967

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x38f21838 _kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib                   0x38e6a643 <redacted> + 39

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x38f33f38 ___psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x38f9b041 _pthread_cond_wait + 41
2   Foundation                          0x2eff874f <redacted> + 195
3   AppName                             0x0011a5a1 0x66000 + 738721
4   Foundation                          0x2f06ddc7 <redacted> + 1063
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x38f9ac5d <redacted> + 141
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x38f9abcf __pthread_start + 103

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x38f21a84 _mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation                      0x2e654561 <redacted> + 157
2   CoreFoundation                      0x2e652c81 <redacted> + 793
3   CoreFoundation                      0x2e5bd541 _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 525
4   CoreFoundation                      0x2e5bd323 _CFRunLoopRunInMode + 107
5   Foundation                          0x2efab827 <redacted> + 255
6   Foundation                          0x2effc669 <redacted> + 81
7   AppName                             0x00138e95 0x66000 + 863893
8   Foundation                          0x2f06ddc7 <redacted> + 1063
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x38f9ac5d <redacted> + 141
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x38f9abcf __pthread_start + 103

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x38f21a84 _mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation                      0x2e654561 <redacted> + 157
2   CoreFoundation                      0x2e652c81 <redacted> + 793
3   CoreFoundation                      0x2e5bd541 _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 525
4   CoreFoundation                      0x2e5bd323 _CFRunLoopRunInMode + 107
5   Foundation                          0x2eff8651 <redacted> + 321
6   Foundation                          0x2f06ddc7 <redacted> + 1063
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x38f9ac5d <redacted> + 141
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x38f9abcf __pthread_start + 103

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x38f34440 ___select + 20
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x38f9ac5d <redacted> + 141
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x38f9abcf __pthread_start + 103

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x38f34c7c ___workq_kernreturn + 8

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x38f34c7c ___workq_kernreturn + 8

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000     r1: 0x00000000     r2: 0x00000000     r3: 0xffffffff 
    r4: 0x00000006     r5: 0x3ad6118c     r6: 0x17e19650     r7: 0x27d9d924 
    r8: 0x3140f0da     r9: 0x3ad61e30    r10: 0x313f4457    r11: 0x0000000f 
    ip: 0x00000148     sp: 0x27d9d918     lr: 0x38f9ba53     pc: 0x38f341fc 
  cpsr: 0x00000010
```

It's saying that crash is occured on Thread 0 but when i run the app from Xcode, debugger does not show any thread 0 and starts threds from 1 and so on. I am unable to produce this crash.
How can i demystify the crash and where it is heppeing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you got a reason:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for
>   empty array'

You are somewhere trying to access the first element of an empty array.

Doesn't really matter which thread crashed

Comment: But how can I find where it is happening. I am using several Arrays in my project.

Comment: yes this is the fun part. but you should always check if there are any elements in an array before you try to access anyone.

Comment: You should upload the dSYM of that app build and the crash report will be symbolicated and show you where in your app that problem is.